# I connected the front end to the backend I tried it as a test I had this error coming out

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Code screenshots:

[`server package.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzppN.jpg)

[`server index.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMt5P.jpg)

[`client (React) package.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxkra.jpg)

[`client (React) App.jsx`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saPor.jpg)

Error screenshot:

[`Error`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT3F7.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are fetching on the wrong endpoint.

Try fetch('http://localhost:8080/api')